# How can I add labels to proportion barplot showing the amount (not the proportion)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, frequency

I created a proportion barplot:

```
df <- data.frame(speech = c("figurative", "literal", "figurative", "literal"),
             meaning = c("kill", "seek", "seek", "kill"), 
             amount = c(47, 2260, 588, 5639)) 
ggplot(df, aes(x=speech,y=amount, fill=meaning, group = meaning)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position="fill")
```

How can I add labels showing the amount (not the proportion)?

Comment: Did you want to add the amount to the stack bar chart? or did you want to change the y axis to show the amount rather than the proportion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you mean? Adding labels based on the values for *amount*.

```
df <- data.frame(speech = c("figurative", "literal", "figurative", "literal"),
                 meaning = c("kill", "seek", "seek", "kill"), 
                 amount = c(47, 2260, 588, 5639)) 

ggplot(df, aes(x=speech,y=amount, fill=meaning, group = meaning)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position="fill") +
  geom_text(aes(label = amount), position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]